# Как удалить или очистить `RecyclerView`?

Tags: android, recyclerview

У меня есть `RecyclerView` который заполняется списком элементов, полученных из ответа сервера.

Сначала пользователь вводит логи/пароль и выбирает определенный контент, например : контент 1.

После авторизации пользователь попадает на активность с `RecyclerView`, в котором присутствуют поля этого контент 1.

При нажатии на кнопку Back пользователь переходит обратно на главную активность регистрации и выбирает уже контент 2. После нажатия на кнопку Login снова попадает на `RecyclerView`, но вот в нем почему то осталась информация от контент 1, а контент 2 добавилось в конец списка.

**Что я пробовал:**

`recyclerAdapter.Clear();`

`recyclerView.removeAllViewsInLayout();`

`arraylist().clear();`
`notifyDataSetChanged();`

Ничего не помогает

Обработка нажатия кнопки Back в активности :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    recyclerView.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    recyclerView.removeAllViews();
    unswerFromMain.clear();
    recyclerAdapter.updateAdapter(unswerFromMain);

}
```

Метод сохранения отредактированного контента

```
public void updateAdapter (ArrayList<Unswer> updateUnswer){

    getUnswer.clear();
    getUnswer.addAll(updateUnswer);

    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: Код, связанный с проблемой?

Comment: Извините, я добавил код обработки нажатия кнопки Back и код обновления контента в  самом адаптере.

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел корень моего зла. Вся проблема была **не в очистке адаптера**, а в том что я **не очищал ArrayList** который передавал из главной активности регистрации. Этот ArrayList содержал поля контента 1 и когда я, будучи на активности с  RecyclerView, жал кнопку Back то **возвращался в главную активность с уже заполненным ArrayList данных** о контенте 1. Потом я выбирал контент 2 и данные о нем просто добавлялись в конец ArrayList.

Я полностью убрал все методы с onBackPressed() , кроме super.onBackPressed(); и все нормально стало работать. Благодарю всех за потраченное время!

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь переиспользовать адаптер.
А вам нужно создать новый адаптер и назначить его для вашего списка.

Comment: Дополните ваш ответ более детальным описанием решения проблемы или кодом, чтобы пользователям было легче понять ваш ответ.

Comment: @Yuri  для этого нужно, чтобы задающий вопрос пользователь показал, как он создаёт адаптер.

Comment: Я понимаю, но моё дело - предложить :) А то некоторые несознательные личности могут отметить, как комментарий